# i want to trigger clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to show alert when user clicking on  link "Go"... but the function does not run...
.....help me please.....
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="js/trip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $('.clk-btn').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("Error");
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <a class="clk-btn"  href="#"  >Go</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many things.

Answer (score 4):

You should make use of document ready:

```
$(function(){
    $('.clk-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Error");
    });
});
```

Otherwise the click handler will not be bound to your anchor.

```js
$(function(){
     $('.clk-btn').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("Error");
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clk-btn"  href="#"  >Go</a>
```

Comment: Grammar: `bound` is the past tense of `bind`